React: How to have VSCode auto-complete with single-quotes in most places, but double-quotes in JSX tags?
For my React TypeScript project, the ESLint specifies using single-quotes in general, but double-quotes in JSX/TSX tags. Here's a mini version of the ".eslintrc.json" file:
{
    "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
    "rules": {
        "quotes": [ "error", "single" ],
        "jsx-quotes": [ "error", "prefer-double" ],
        // etc.
    }
}

VSCode correctly identifies quotes based on these settings, and will show an error if the quotes are incorrect. What I'm hoping to do is configure VSCode's auto-complete to function the same way. When I'm in a ".tsx" file, auto-completing in the main code, such as file imports, should use single-quotes:
import React from 'react';

And auto-completes in the TSX, such as attribute values, should use double-quotes:
return <div className=""></div>;

VSCode correctly identifies the quotes in respect to the ".eslintrc.json" file, i.e. if I changed the quotes in either of the examples then it would label it as an error. But I can't figure out how to get the auto-complete to function the same way.

By default, it uses other examples in the file to determine which type of quotes to use for auto-complete, but it's either "all single-quotes" or "all double-quotes".
If I add one of these to my "setting.json", then it uses one type of quotes in all cases:
    "typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single"
    "typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "double"

This setting seems to have no effect (and setting it to "braces" or "none" isn't what I want):
    "typescript.preferences.jsxAttributeCompletionStyle": "auto"

I also tried using the Prettier extension, but I couldn't get it to work in VSCode, so a solution that doesn't use that would be ideal.
Is there a way to get the specific combination that I want?

I ran into this issue. So the quote style option is for quick fixes, which I've never used and don't even know what is. The second option will default jsx attiributes into x="" or x={}.
So the solution? It's Prettier :) I kinda know from your post that you've tried, but having Prettier as a preprocessor in front of ES Lint is the only viable solution. I don't know how you have your workflow configured, but if you enable Prettier to format on save and then run ES Lint aftwerwards, everythings is fine as candy.
On a personal note, Prettier is all you need. Those linters are too opinionated.
